# Do we really need all the feeds in chat?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Machines are taking over [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz). That is, there are currently more posts by the feed bot than actual user activity. So, couldn't we drop [the feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/151/?tab=feeds) that aren't security-related? We would also make the chat look more inviting and on-topic by not burying the rare signs of human activity between unrelated feeds.

**xkcd feed:** Other sites have [democratically](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/is-the-xkcd-feed-in-the-chat-really-necessary/272) [decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/do-we-want-xkcd-autposted-in-chat/7080) to remove the xkcd feed from their chats and I think the same arguments would work for the DMZ. The majority of xkcd strips isn't about security - and those that are could be posted manually.

**SO Blog feed:** It's nice to stay informed about the developments at SO but since new blog posts are also prominently announced in the sidebar on every page, it wouldn't be necessary to auto-post them in chat.

Do we want to keep having all xkcd strips and SO Blog articles auto-posted in chat?

Comment: I'm supportive of this, but let's give it a few days so that people can comment (some may be off on holiday at present as well - kids are off school at the moment here, for example)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I agree that there is no hurry - waiting a bit will not hurt anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we do not need them. Yes, please remove them.

While I (like everybody else) love XKCD, there is no need for it in chat. If I want to read it, I know where to find it. (Plus, it should be read together with the title which is not posted in chat.)

The blog feed is at least a bit more on topic, but nine times out of ten it is just promotion of something I don't want to read anyway (like [another episode of the podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/13/stack-overflow-podcast-104-jenn-schiffer-talks-us-fog-creeks-new-glitch/) or [some random silly data analysis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/28/realistic-developer-fiction/)).

Instead of being spoon fed mostly irrelevant content from a bot, I think it would be better if we the users post things we think others can be interested in.